# Why Project's build.gradle is not showing？

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

[image]

[image]

Why is Project's build.gradle not showing up in Android mode?

Just like the picture below, the .gradle file in the project root directory can also be displayed in Android mode.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njrrl.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it at here. You choose to display the project instead the Android.

[image]

Comment: I know this is two modes, but in Android mode, the .gradle file in the project root directory is not displayed, it can be displayed normally.

Answer (score 0):

You changed the display mode. Notice that the first image, you configured to "Project Mode" and the second one is in "Android Mode". It's on the upper-left corner of the "project" tree view.

[image]

Comment: I know this is two modes, but in Android mode, the .gradle file in the project root directory is not displayed, it can be displayed normally.

Comment: Its probably a bug. Did you try restarting?

Answer (score 0):

Your using **`project`** structure better to use **`android`** structure view

secound thing is if you want to use project structure then **`project->build.gradle`** is your project level **`gradle file`** for `Ex.` **`AndroidWeather/build.gradle`**

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the caches get messed up. Try this:

- Close the project in Android Studio
- Delete the .idea folder in the project folder:
- In Android Studio, File / New / Import Project... and select the folder of the project

Note, to delete the folder:

```
cd /path/to/project
rm -rf .idea
```

Now you should see the project-level build.gradle in the Android scope.